# Replace Cell Data with Note in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: Image1]

Hi, is it possible to replace the Cell Data with the data from the note in Google Sheets?

So it looks something like this
[image: Image2]

and then if possible delete the note as well.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [`Range.getNote()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnote) method?

Comment: Please don't rely on image; instead add a table, or a link to (a copy of) your Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `Range` class comes with [`getNote`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnote) and [`clearNote`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearNote()) methods

```js
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet       = spreadsheet.getSheetByName( 'your-sheet-name' );
var range       = sheet.getRange( 3, 4 );
var note        = range.getNote();

range.setValue( note ).clearNote();
```